# Log4j2 and maven - Picking wrong config file

Tags: java, maven, logging, configuration, log4j2

I have two projects (P1 & P2) which are using Log4j2 logging. Each of the projects have their separate log4j2.xml placed in src/main/resources directory (according to maven structure).

The issue is, when I run any program in a project (say P1) through my IDE (Eclipse) it picks out the correct log4j2.xml. (May be because Eclipse resolves the classpath properly). But when I run the same program from command line, it picks out the log4j2.xml of project P2.

I have tried multiple time to "clean and install" the maven projects but to no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of both your projects, particularly how they are related to each other?

Comment: Also, if your target artifact is an executable jar, can you open it with an archive manager and check whether the expected log4j configuration file is inside?

Comment: Project P2 is a parent project. Project P1 is dependent on P2, and P1 contains the executable program that I am running from command line.

Comment: And yes, P1.jar file contains the correct log4j2.xml file.

Comment: Log4J will pick up the first config file it finds on the classpath if it's not specifically configured to pick a specific one. If you have competing configs you are at the mercy of the classloader/etc. Consider specifying a qualified name and keeping them out of the classpath root.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I do think that could be the issue. Could you please elaborate a bit on what you mean by "specifying a qualified name"? (The name of file is pretty much standard).

Comment: I can't cite any references, but I personally think that having a non-POM Maven parent project is not such a good design. Perhaps you could have a parent POM project where both P1 and P2 are its children.

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is a good idea to avoid putting config files inside jar files to avoid this exact problem. If you don't have a choice in the matter, you need to control the classpath such that the jar with the desired log4j2.xml precedes the jar with the undesired config file.

Also, you can specify the location of the config file with a system property: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location